# Test case running twice not once

Tags: python-2.7, nose, python-unittest

This test is supposed to log in a user by calling the `TALogin.test()` super method, which passes the credentials (URL, username/password, etc.) and then logs the user out.  However, when I run this it runs the `TALogin` part and then closes and runs it again but does the logout portion.

So, I get the following:

```
Ran 2 tests in 65.990s

OK
```

I would just like it to run once; login and then do the logout.

Here's my code:

```
from BaseTestCase import BaseTestCase
from pages.BasePage import BasePage
from login.TALogin_Test import TALogin
import nose

class TALogout_Test(TALogin):

    def setUp(self):
        super(TALogout_Test, self).setUp()

    def test(self):
        super(TALogout_Test, self).test()
        base_obj = BasePage(self.driver)
        base_obj.do_logout()

    def tearDown(self):
        super(TALogout_Test, self).tearDown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   nose.run(defaultTest=__name__)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're not telling `nose` that you want to only run the tests in `TALogout_Test`. It's running both `TALogin.test` and `TALogout_Test.test`.

One way to specify the class you want to load tests from is with `nose.run()`'s `suite` parameter, and a `unittest.TestLoader`'s [`loadTestsFromTestCase()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase) method:

```
from unittest import defaultTestLoader
nose.run(suite=defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(TALogout_Test))
```

Comment: It's a bingo! Thanks!